# MailChimp does not accept an email ending in @usace.army.mil

Tags: email, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

When I do an http post to a list with an email ending in @usace.army.mil I get the error message back (that says the email is fake)
I know the email is not fake is there anyway to override this?

:

```
 Invoke-RestMethod : {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Invalid 
Resource","status":400,"detail":"Fred.T.Tracy@usace.army.mil looks fake or invalid, please enter a real email address.","instance":""}
At line:69 char:29
+ ...     $gist = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$URL$endpoint" -Head ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: Provide a broader traceback

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer to your question is no, there in no way to override this.

Mailchimp support informed me that it does not allow addresses on the domain usace.army.mil to be added to its lists.

Your only recourse is to ask your subscriber to ask the admin on usace.army.mil to email compliance@mailchimp.com and ask that the block be lifted.

(p.s. to the original poster, please can I suggest that you remove the person's email address from your code snippet for privacy reasons.)